# Materializecss responsive menu not working?

Tags: materialize

I am using materializecss but the responsive menu is not werking?? I coppied the exact html from their website it looks good but een scaling the window to a smaller size the button appears but when I click it it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you link the js library of materializecss into your html?

[Url to the materialize library](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js)

also you need Jquery for this to work

[Url to jquery library](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js)

after that you have ti initialize the reponsive menu. In your js file like this:

```
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

Hope it helps!